# What does an atom of a person mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

**Brookfield would not have an atom of him different.**
Reference: Good-Bye Mr. Chips , Chapter 15
What does actually the writer want to refer to in this sentence? Does it mean that Brookfield would never have any other person like Mr. Chips? What does the word atom mean in this context particularly?

Comment: In 1934 most people thought that an atom was the smallest part of matter.  Brookfield would not change even one tiny part of Mr Chips. Brookfield sees no fault in Mr Chips and totally admires him.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey This is answer-worthy IMO

Comment: @gotube - there are enough dictionary definitions of 'atom' meaning 'tiny piece' that I didn't want to reward a low-quality question with a fully-fledged answer.